# Escaping JS inside PHP echo using entities

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

( there are a lot of question here on SE about escaping JS in PHP , but I still could not identify the best method to use as a rule in all situations .)

Consider the script on the page :

```
echo '<a class="x2delete"  onclick="if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " +  ' . $img  . ') ) { DeleteImage('."'".$img."'"." ,' ".$count."'".'); return false; }" href="javascript:;"></a>';
```

Which of course did not work, so I tried to escape it :

```
confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete ?\")
```

I also tried `'` `/\` , `\/` , and various others , but all escaping methods failed until I decided to just use the proper XML entity representation, `&quot;`

```
if ( confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to delete ?&quot; +  ' . $img  . ')
```

So `&quot;` works fine for this specific code. ( Can it even be considered as escaping ?? )

My question is :

1. Is that correct to use it ?
2. Will escaping with `&quot;` will always work for me while `echoing js in php ?`
   Can I just always use it instead of the other escaping methods ( that for me , are simply trial and error.. )
3. Will it always work on all browsers ?
4. ( a bonus non mandatory / related question ) . why do I need the parenthesis around the `confirm()` ?? writing only

   `if confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to delete ?&quot;)`

gave me an error of missing parenthesis. I was sure it will work in a single condition / line.

Comment: You can try asking this question in CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) the community there is expecting to answer this kind of questions.

Comment: @Joraid - But I am not searching for a code-specific answer ( also, I am quit confused as regarding to the overlap between those two sites )

Comment: +1 your question is very interesting. SO is mainly for code specific answers, it's it may consider several valid answer (a matter of opinion)  then as i noticed, the guys here are not into this kind of stuff. However, by reading some questions in CR, they actually discuss patterns and practices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert  a literal backslash, which means using `\\`:

```
echo '<a class="x2delete"  onclick="if ( confirm(\\"Are you sure you want to delete...
```

Comment: Ok. thanks.. But I was not really searching for a code-specific answer - now my code also works with `&quot;`. My question is if it is ok to ALWAYS use it inside PHP echo ( that, or equivalent entities ) ..

Answer (score 0):

This is the final result that we want, right?

Either single quot, or double quot:

single quot:

```
 confirm("are you sure you want to delete?");
```

double quot:

```
 confirm('are you sure you want to delete?');
```

So the question now is, how to wrap that into a php code. Well, there's no "best" practice. The only good practice is to do it in the way that is **readable** for you, for your **fellow programs** who work on the same team, and for **joiner programmers** who might join the team later. Here I will share a few practices that I saw during in the several projects I worked on.

Once there is a pattern in a project, it's suggested to follow that pattern. So if your project is following backslash escaping, then it's better to just do that.

Practice 1 : close php tag, write html, open php again. Open php for inline vars.

```
?>
<a onclick="confirm('Do you like this patter?')" href="<?php echo $ref_link ?>">Click Me!</a>
<?
```

Practice 2 : use double quot outside, single ones inside, escaped double quot for inner strings:

```
echo "<a class='x2delete'  onclick='if ( confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete +  " . $img  . "\") ) { DeleteImage(\"".$img."\" ,\"".$count."\"); return false; }' href='javascript:;'>Click Me</a>";
```

Keep in mind that browsers (Firefox in this example) will use double quot  so even if you write

```
onclick='confirm("Is this ok?")'
```

it will be parsed as:

```
onclick="confirm("Is this ok?")"
```

As for your questions 1-3, even if everyone tells you 'yes' it will work. You cannot really know until your try if for your self. Browsers change, languages change, compilers change, so the best way to know is to test it personally.

As for your last question:

```
if confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?')
```

You cannot do that, `if` is a language construct and the condition must be inclosed into a pair of parentheses `()`. What you can skip is the condition body `{}` by having one statement body. I believe this is common among programming languages, *at least the ones I tried*.

```
if(true)alert("yes"); else alert("no");
```

It's syntactically valid. But it is considered bad style.

Comment: but what about `entities` ?

Comment: As far as i know, &quot will work just fine. But IMO, personally, I wouldn't use it cuz it make the code less readable (I don't like it's look) and have more characters, hence, increase file size and more network transfer time (if you have hundreds of strings). Even though it won't affect that much. But that's my opinion. Besides, I've never seen anyone actually following that practice.